# Make a video in sequential order from frames

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have saved images in the sequential format- 0.jpg, 1.jpg, ---,99.jpg, 100.jpg. I am making video from these frames by using ffmpeg for conversion:

cmd1 = 'ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type  glob -i "/home/ubuntu/17/1_1/*.jpg" /home/ubuntu/17_a.avi'

But ffmpeg is not reading the images in sequential manner. How to make a video that take frames in a sequential order.

Comment: ```-vf
        drawtext=text='%{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5```
        If you pass drawtext, you can actually print frame number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour for ffmpeg is to read images in continuous numeric sequence. But since you have specified `glob` pattern, it uses that. Drop `pattern_type` and specify the correct pattern in the filename field.

`ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i "/home/ubuntu/17/1_1/%d.jpg" /home/ubuntu/17_a.avi'`

Comment: What is the glob pattern sequence? In what sequence does a glob pattern reads files?

Answer (score 1):

*But ffmpeg is not reading the images in sequential manner. How to make a video that take frames in a sequential order.*

globs generally provide lexicographical order, i.e. `0` to `9` are treated as letters thus, if you sort numbers from `1` to `100` (inclusive) it goes like `1`, `10`, `100`, `11`, `12`...

I do not know if `ffmpeg`'s glob has option to use natsort, but if you can rename your files it should be easy to pad with zeros using `python` and thus making lexicographical ordering same as natsort. Please create copy of catalog with your jpg files and then run there following `python` code

```
import glob,os
for jpg in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    os.rename(jpg,jpg.zfill(7))
```

which should rename

> 0.jpg, 1.jpg, ---,99.jpg, 100.jpg

to

> 000.jpg, 001.jpg, ---,099.jpg, 100.jpg

then run your `ffmpeg` command and check if it worked correctly. `.zfill` does pad with zeros to specified width, I used `7` as last name `100.jpg` has 7 characters. If it would be `1000.jpg` then at least 8 would be required and so on.